# Move cursor after yank according to direction

Tags: vimscript, cursor-movement

I want to use `yt<anyChar>` for yanking and for jumping, so that cursor moves to the first char before `<anyChar>`. For backward moving this is working by default (after `yT<anyChar>` cursor moves to the first char after `<anyChar>` and I even can use `;` and `,` for additional jumps).

In my Emacs+Evil config I've done it by simply advising evil-yank function:

```
    (defun evil-yank-after (beg end type register yank-handler)
      (if (= (point) beg)
        (goto-char (1- end))
      (goto-char beg)))

    (advice-add #'evil-yank :after #'evil-yank-after)
```

In vim I guess approach is totally different?

Answer (score 3):

This is not so easy, because you need to get one additional char after the `t` command. However, I think you can map it using an expression mapping like this:

```
omap <expr> t 't'.nr2char(getchar())."`]"
```

This maps the `t` command to the `t`, gets one character from the user using `getchar()` function and then moves the cursor to the [last character of the previously yanked or changed command](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#%27])

Note, this is a very simple mapping, that might not work correctly in error cases or some special cases (and probably also brakes the `;` and `,` command), so beware of some unexpected behaviour. (e.g. take a look at my ftimproved plugin for how many special cases you have to consider).

Comment: Thanks! To restrict this to yanking only I need something like `nnoremap <expr> yt 'yt'.nr2char(getchar())."`]"`? No better way?

Comment: Is there any analogue of `getchar()` for variable length string until `<CR>`? To do the same for `/`?

Comment: Sure, `:h input()`